# 一度の Esc で autocomplete-plus のペインを閉じて、command mode を有効にしたい

Tags: atom-editor

Atom で、vim-mode と autocomplete-plus を使用しています。

insert mode で入力していると、autocomplete-plus によって候補のペインが表示されます。ここで Esc を押すと、候補のペインが閉じるだけです。このとき、一度の Esc によって候補を閉じて、かつ command mode に移行したいのです。

調べてみると以下のエントリーを見つけたのですが、うまく動きませんでした。
[Almost Surely: Atom for a Vim User](http://felixjung.io/blog/2014/12/20/atom-form-a-vim-user/)

このような内容です。
keymap.cson

```
'.autocomplete-plus input.hidden-input':
  'escape': 'vim-mode:activate-command-mode'
```

どなたか解決できる方、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

一応動きましたが、候補が選択されないまま途中でcommand modeに移行してしまうので
これでいいのか微妙なのですけど...

```
'atom-text-editor:not(mini) .autocomplete-plus.autocomplete-suggestion-list':
  'escape': 'vim-mode:activate-command-mode'
```

Comment: 一度回答いたしましたがhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456995/how-do-i-write-a-custom-command-in-atom を読んで色々試行してみた結果、Escに`'escape': 'autocomplete-plus:confirm'`を割り振って二回Escを叩くのが現実的という身も蓋もない回答を結局得ました...

Comment: この質問で要求している挙動はこれなので、すごく助かりました！

Comment: @karur4n 本回答で解決した場合には回答の承認をよろしくお願いします。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers